# Registering a destination site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have enabled Content Organizer feature so that we can route documents from one library to another
However although the deletion/move to recycle bin works the crucial one move to another location  says there are no registered destination locations - does anyone know how to register a location (SharePoint online) and indeed if this still can be done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To setup a registered destination, you can follow the steps below:

- Click the gear on the upper right corner of the site and select Site settings.
- Click Manage site features under Site Actions.
- Activate the Content Organizer feature. You will get the "Drop off Library" as well as 2 new options in the Site Settings, Content Organizer Rules and Content Organizer Settings.
- Select Content Organizer Settings in the Site Administration section.
  Scroll down to the bottom and copy the Web service URL.
- Go to your SharePoint admin center and select records management.
- In the Connection Settings section, type the Display name and paste the Web service URL to the Send to URL.
- Select the Send to action and add the Explanation.
- Click Add Connection then the send to another location function should work.

If the error still exists, please take a reference to this article:
https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/understanding-the-record-center-in-sharepoint-online-part-2/

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response very useful. Unfortunately despite following those steps and the specific points in the supporting article about the destination locations still not being registered (the site is registered and I have used content type etc) still showing as unavailable